# JS Hover Over One Item to Make Another Move

Tags: javascript

I've got a simple text button with an image of an arrow next to it. I'm wanting the arrow image to move when someone hovers over the button.

I currently have this working in one instance with JS 'document.getElementById...', but I have several buttons across my site that I'd like to have the same behavior. My first thought would be to use a class instead of an id, and use the same functions.

For whatever reason, `document.getElementsByClassName` doesn't work - even in one instance.

Here's a simpler version to demonstrate - View on Codepen: https://codepen.io/sdorr/pen/JxYNpg

HTML

```
<HTML>
    <a href="#" class="button" onmouseover="move()" onmouseout="moveBack()">hover over me</a>

    <div id="block"></div>

    <a href="#" class="button" onmouseover="moveAlt()" onmouseout="moveBackAlt()">hover over me</a>

    <div class="block"></div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.button {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: cyan;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#block {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}

.block {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

JS

```
function move() {
    document.getElementById("block").style.marginLeft = "35px";
}

function moveBack() {
    document.getElementById("block").style.marginLeft = "0px";
}

function moveAlt() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("block").style.marginLeft = 
"35px";
}

function moveBackAlt() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("block").style.marginLeft = 
"0px";
}
```

First off, why isn't the behavior with a class working but an id works fine?

Secondly, would a class solve this issue and be scalable across all buttons with the same two functions (onmouseover / onmouseout)?

If not, any ideas on a solution? I currently have a solution I found using jQuery that does work, but when hovering over one button, all arrow images move across the site. I don't necessarily mind this behavior because only one button is really in view at a time - but I'm trying to learn JS and solve problems with my own solutions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I greatly appreciate your desire to learn on your own and not rely on premade solutions. Keep that spirit and you will go places!

When it comes to `getElementsById`, we know this should work for one element, since the function returns a single Element.

**However, what does `getElementsByClassName` return?**
(see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

It returns an `HTMLCollection` which you can iterate over to change an single element's `style`.

So, to get this to work with JavaScript you need to write a function that will be able to identify the particular `div.block` you want to move. But, this puts you back to where you started, needing some particular identifier, like an `id` or a `dataset` value to pass to the function.

Alternately, based on the HTML structure you provide, you could look for `nextElementSibling` on the `a` that get's clicked. But I would set up an `eventListener` rather than adding a JS function as a value to the `onmouseenter` property.

```
const btns = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
/*** UPDATE forEach is a NodeList method, and will fail on HTMLCollection ***/
/* this fails -> Sorry! ~~btns.forEach(button=>{~~
/* the following will work
/**********/
for (let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++){
    btns[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
        //we pass e to the function to get the event and to be able to access this
        const block = this.nextElementSibling;
        block.style.marginLeft = "35px";
    })

    btns[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
        const block = this.nextElementSibling;
        block.style.marginLeft = "0";
    })
}
```

But with siblings, there is a CSS-only solution.

We can use the `Adjacent Sibling Selector` combined with the `:hover` state selector and no JavaScript is needed, if we are just moving back and forth.

```
.button:hover+.block {
    margin-left: 35px;
}
```

See the Snipped Below

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.button {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: cyan;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.block {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
}

.button:hover+.block {
    margin-left: 35px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">hover over me</a>

<div class="block"></div>


<a href="#" class="button">hover over me</a>

<div class="block"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Vecta mentioned, [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array-like. You'll need to do something like this to get the first element:

```
function moveAlt() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("block")[0].style.marginLeft = "35px";
}

function moveBackAlt() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("block")[0].style.marginLeft = "0px";
}
```

However a better solution might be to use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), which operates similarly to jQuery's `$()` syntax:

```
function moveAlt() {
    document.querySelector(".block").style.marginLeft = "35px";
}

function moveBackAlt() {
    document.querySelector(".block").style.marginLeft = "0px";
}
```

Comment: The issue with `querySelector` is that it only returns the first element that matches the query. It won't necessarily return the closest `.block` to the `button`. `querySelectorAll` returns all elements that match the query as a `NodeList`.